# If I mispronounce Allah’s name in recitation or dhikr, do I have to renew my faith?

Tags: fiqh, arabic, tawba, kufr

If I mispronounce Allah’s glorious names in recitation or dhikr, do I have to utter shahadah and do tobah ? What about mistakes in Quran recitation?

Answer (score 1):

Alsalam alikum brother/syster. First of all it never wrong to do ask for forgivness for what ever because we never know when we do wrong.

Now to the answer. If you dont mean it then inshallah the hadith of the prophet is the thing that applies which is

> "All work are with intentions, if you were travling with the intent that it is for Allah sake then it is going to count for Allah's sake, and if you were travling for other then that it is going to count for what you are travling for"
> [Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1)

So if you intend to say Allah's name and you accdently miss pronuce it then inshallah it is no problem, but as said before there is nothing wrong with making dua for forgivness. After all prophet Noah [as] when he was asking his people to follow the path of Allah he told them

> saying, ‘Seek your Lord’s forgiveness, ˹for˺ He is truly Most Forgiving. He will shower you with abundant rain, supply you with wealth and children, and give you gardens as well as rivers.
> [Source](https://quran.com/71/10)

So asking for forgivness is not just for you'r sins but there is rewards with it inshallah and maybe some worldy reward with an afterlife reward. So ask for forgivness always for everything you have doubt in.

Secound of all. If you'r native language is not arabic or you strugel with pronouncing some words then inshallah as long as you try to do it correctly then you will get double reward for it and for trying.

May Allah guide is all.
Hope that answers you'r question.

Comment: Welcome here in Islam SE and thanks for contributing. If you want to make your answers more valuable, it would be nice if you could add a link to the hadith e.g. on sunnah.com.

Comment: @Jeschu Thanks, i just added the sources. I will try inshallah to keep on doing this next time.